# SQL Datareader is not holding the values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader

I have been working with a project for last 4 months. We are using a custom framework for the development. The problem I am talking about, was working for all other classes. But for the first time I am facing this weird incident. Now Straight to break point.

My framework code is like

```
public static List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity> GetAllNotSetBillableCources()
        {
            try
            {
                List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity> entities = new List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity>();
                string command = SELECT;
                SqlConnection sqlConnection = MSSqlConnectionHandler.GetConnection();
                SqlDataReader dataReader = QueryHandler.ExecuteSelect(command, sqlConnection);

                entities = Maps(dataReader);
                dataReader.Close();
                return entities;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
        }
```

In the above method the dataReader is sent to Maps method.

The Maps method is ......

```
private static List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity> Maps(SqlDataReader theReader)
    {
        SQLNullHandler nullHandler = new SQLNullHandler(theReader);
        // the incident is happening here, the SQLNullHandler is given below.
        List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity> entities = null;
        while (theReader.Read())
        {
            if (entities == null)
            {
                entities = new List<ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity>();
            }
            ViewNotSetBillableCoursesEntity entity = Mapper(nullHandler);
            entities.Add(entity);
        }

        return entities;
    }
```

The SQLNullHandler is given below:

```
puplic Class SQLNullHandler
  {
      private IDataReader _reader;
      public SQLNullHandler(IDataReader reader)
        {
            _reader = reader;
        }
      #region Get Null value
    public static object GetNullValue(int Value)
    {
        if(Value==0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }

    public static object GetNullValue(double Value)
    {
        if (Value == 0)
        { 
            return null; 
        }
        else
        { 
            return Value; 
        }
    }

    public static object GetNullValue(decimal Value)
    {
        if (Value == 0)
        { 
            return null; 
        }
        else
        { 
            return Value; 
        }
    }

    public static object GetNullValue(DateTime Value)
    {
        if(DateTime.MinValue==Value)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }

    public static object GetNullValue(string Value)
    {
        if(Value.Length<=0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
      public IDataReader  Reader
    {
        get{return _reader;}
    }
     public bool IsNull(int index)
    {
        return _reader.IsDBNull(index);
    }

    public int GetInt32(int i)
    {
        return _reader.IsDBNull(i)? 0 : _reader.GetInt32(i);
    }

    public byte GetByte(int i)
    {
        return _reader.IsDBNull(i)? (byte)0 : _reader.GetByte(i);
    }
           //and so on for all possible type for this app
  }
```

The Funny thing is for all these classes these methods and lines of code work very fine, but in this scenario after the line SQLNullHandler nullHandler = new SQLNullHandler(theReader); the datareder becomes empty. 
My questions are

1. Why is this Happening and next,
2. what can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you verified that the SqlDataReader returned by your db call contains rows (i.e., isn't null itself)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it. while debugging the program. It holds the value until its being sent as a parameter in the nullhandler constructor.

Comment: Please post more code from `SQLNullHandler` - preferably using cut and paste rather than just typing it out as you've done here (the code you've given wouldn't compile).

Comment: What role does `SQLNullHandler` play in the framework?  Is it possible that something within that class is nulling the reader?

Comment: @Tim SQLNullHandler is return default values if any of column returned from the DB gives a null value. I have edited the SQLNullHandler CLass please have a look again.